# Html input range start and stop dragging event

Tags: javascript, html, events, input

I need to have a start and stop event on input range, so I can detect when dragging start and when it ends. Are these good events to use or is there a better way?

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input')

input.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  console.log('start')
}, false);


input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  console.log('end')
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="input" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

These events seem fine, but try just clicking on the input without dragging it. The console only logs "start" if you don't change the value.

If you want to capture that, you can just use the "mouseup" event.

```
input.addEventListener("mouseup", function-here);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [`mousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) and/or [`mouseup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event) too because the user can click anywhere in this range, and don't have to drag it necessary.